# Unable to parse JSON result

Tags: json, here-api

I'm trying to implement the HERE.COM routing API.  It utilizes JSON and a callback function to return the results.  Here's the code I have:

```
    function GetResults() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        strSource = 'http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&representation=overview&metricSystem=imperial&jsonCallback=renderNarrative';
        script.src = strSource
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    function renderNarrative(response) {
        alert(response.route[0].summary.baseTime);
    }
```

The resulting JSON object is returned, but the reading of that object fails.  (Note: If you remove the jsonCallback parameter you can run the source in a seperate browser window to see the returned JSON information.)  It is properly constructed, and can be viewed using a JSON parsing routine that iterates through the entire data structure.  However, my attempts to read the specific information via direct reference fails.  Specifically, I receive the following error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

I've done similar work with the MapQuest API and it worked fine, but this one is not working.  Someone suggested I use the JSON.parse function, but it fails, because the results are already parsed before being returned.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing....

Comment: so `console.log(response)`. hitting that url manually suggests it should be `response.metaInfo`

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that I'm not great at this, but I'm 99% sure that metaInfo is a different section of the JSON-returned data structure.

Comment: well, log the response, most debuggers will format it nicely and let you click down in it.

Comment: Yes, I did log the response.  And I see the values.  And I can't seem to get it to work.  According to the log, it looks like response.route[0].summary.baseTime is the correct reference, but it returns an error.  Thus, my post.

Comment: well, work your way down the tree. access response.route, then response.route[0], etc.. and see where it blows up.

Comment: Marc, I'm not sure why you're being purposefully difficult.  It blows up exactly where I stated it blows up.  Specifically, it says that "Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined ".  I don't know how to get around that error.  I don't know why I'm getting that error.  I appreciate your "help", but so far you've only told me how to find the error, which is what I already know.....

Comment: so `route` is not an array, or is an empty array. that's all I can tell you. I'm not going to go try and prettyprint that huge output blob...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. Apparently, the data is being returned inside of a second "response" object. So, I need to use response.response.route[0].summary.baseTime. Weird.

Comment: Makes sense as the First response is the javascript variable which contains the response, where as the API returns itself a wrapper called "response"  https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&departure=now